# NodeJS unusual Require - what's going on here?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Per the documentation at https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

What is happening on this next line and why does this work?

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
```

From what I understand, it's merely wrapping exec into another object ie

```
var a = { exec }
// a is now { exec: exec }
```

but then there's an assignment.. **-Mind Blown-**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code example:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
```

produces the same result as:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
```

This is known as **destructuring assignment** and is something new in ES2015 (ES6) and is described here: [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on MDN.  It allows various shortcuts for assigning one or more properties from a source object to various types of destinations.  In this case, the source object is the result of `require('child_process')` and the desired destination is a single variable named `exec` which is to receive a single named property from the source.

It gets even more useful when you specify multiple properties:

```
const { exec, spawn, fork } = require('child_process');
```

This creates module level variables named `exec`, `spawn` and `fork` that contain those exported properties from the child process module.  Before destructuring assignment, one would have either done:

```
const child = require('child_process');
const exec = child.exec;
const spawn = child.spawn;
const fork = child.fork;
```

or would have just done this:

```
const child = require('child_process');
```

And, then used `child.exec()` and `child.spawn()` and `child.fork()` to use those methods.  As you can see the destructuring assignment is a significant shortcut.  There are many forms of destructuring and you can do more advanced things such as specify the name of the receiving variable to be different than the property named and destructuring can be used with arrays, not only objects.

Here are several other reference articles on the topic:

[Destructuring and parameter handling in ECMAScript 6](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html)

[Code Examples of destructing in ECMAScript 6](https://gist.github.com/mikaelbr/9900818)

[Explanation of Destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html)

Comment: @Jacksonkr - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is a special notation that comme with ES6 specification.
Here, you extract the value of the property `exec` of the object return by the require in a variable with the same name.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
// Equals
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
```

You can extract somme property a an object like this.

```
const { exec, spawn, fork } = require('child_process');
let { a, b } = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' };
```

It's particularly useful when you load libraries.

This is call [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)